# How to hide DIV using class when field is Empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a PHP **While** statement on my page. I would like to hide DIV with the **class** name "coupon" for each record that has empty field `$rows['deal'];`. This is what my code currently looks like. How can I alter to accomplish this. Thank You much!!!

```
<?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>        <!-- QUERY FOR PAGE 1 RECORDS -->
<div id="main">
<div id="client_name"><?php echo $rows['client_name']; ?></div>
<div id="phone"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></div>
<div id="client_square"></div>
<div id="client_rectangle"></div>
<img id="client_img" src="<?php echo $rows['client_img']; ?>">
<a id="edit" href="update_edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><img id="edit_img" src="images/edit_record.png"></a>
<span class="coupon" id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: There is too many `span` with same class then how can they identify? First put some unique class....

Comment: It seems like all of these solutions seem to hide DIV for every record, not each record. For example, when I tried Amit's solution it hides ALL coupons, regardless of whether DEAL field is empty or not.

Comment: While loop prints data one by one so when we put condition inside that then that is working for one by one record not all......

Comment: If the field `deal` is blank for every record then it will not displaying in all, but otherwise it is perfect solution for your case..... as per you query..... for understand that you can use else and write some code inside that... So you got how they works.

Comment: Looks like it was something on my side. Looks good now thank you all

Comment: Ok, if my answer is useful to you then you can accept it as per stackoverflow..... :)

Comment: Since Amit was the first to respond I had to give it to him. I will give you an up one and a very gracious thank you;) Very much helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on this way:

```
<?php if($rows['deal']){ ?>
<span class="coupon" id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Full code

```
<?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>        <!-- QUERY FOR PAGE 1 RECORDS -->
<div id="main">
<div id="client_name"><?php echo $rows['client_name']; ?></div>
<div id="phone"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></div>
<div id="client_square"></div>
<div id="client_rectangle"></div>
<img id="client_img" src="<?php echo $rows['client_img']; ?>">
<a id="edit" href="update_edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><img id="edit_img" src="images/edit_record.png"></a>
<?php if($rows['deal']){ ?>
<span class="coupon" id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
    <!-- QUERY FOR PAGE 1 RECORDS -->
    <div id="main">
        <div id="client_name"><?php echo $rows['client_name']; ?></div>
        <div id="phone"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></div>
        <div id="client_square"></div>
        <div id="client_rectangle"></div>
        <img id="client_img" src="<?php echo $rows['client_img']; ?>">
        <a id="edit" href="update_edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><img id="edit_img" src="images/edit_record.png"></a>
        <?php if($rows['deal']){ ?>
            <span class="coupon" id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need javascript for this, add this line:

```
<?php echo ($rows['deal']==""?"style='display:none;'":"") ?>
```

Complete code:

```
<?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>        <!-- QUERY FOR PAGE 1 RECORDS -->
<div id="main">
<div id="client_name"><?php echo $rows['client_name']; ?></div>
<div id="phone"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></div>
<div id="client_square"></div>
<div id="client_rectangle"></div>
<img id="client_img" src="<?php echo $rows['client_img']; ?>">
<a id="edit" href="update_edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><img id="edit_img" src="images/edit_record.png"></a>
<span class="coupon" <?php echo ($rows['deal']==""?"style='display:none;'":"") ?> id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

***with PHP:***

You can just count if row has a data so echo it:
this is row with data:

```
<?php
        $row = 'you can add get rows from database';
        if (count($row)) {
            ?>
            <div style="color: red">
                <?php echo $row;  // here you can add your row (foreach) ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

this is row with out data

```
  <?php
    $row = '';
    if (count($row)) {
        ?>
        <div style="color: red">
            <?php echo $row;  // here you can add your row (foreach) ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field is empty, it will have a length of 0. So you can use that logic in order to hide the 'coupon' class

```
    <?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>        <!-- QUERY FOR PAGE 1 RECORDS -->
    <div id="main">
    <div id="client_name"><?php echo $rows['client_name']; ?></div>
    <div id="phone"><?php echo $rows['phone']; ?></div>
    <div id="client_square"></div>
    <div id="client_rectangle"></div>
    <img id="client_img" src="<?php echo $rows['client_img']; ?>">
    <a id="edit" href="update_edit.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><img id="edit_img" src="images/edit_record.png"></a>

<!-- My code -->
    <?php
    if(strlen($rows['deal'] > 0)
        {
    ?>
    <span class="coupon" id="cash_img"></span><span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
<!-- End of my code --> 
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use something like this .

```
<?php if($fildvalue != ''){ ?>
<div><?php  echo $fildvalue; ?> </div>
<?php } ?>
```

so div will be created only when their is an value

Answer (score 0):

Check the data row and put all the HTML tags which you want to hide in case if it is empty or not set.

```
<?php if(isset($rows['deal']) && !empty($rows['deal'])){ ?>
    <span class="coupon" id="deal_text"><?php echo $rows['deal']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

In PHP, empty() function is able to check **NULL value**, **empty string** and **zero** in return.